# Reputation notification value is occasionally wrong

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

Over the last week or so I've noticed that the reputation notification is quite often completely wrong. Roughly speaking this error seems to happen for around 10% of the notifications that I get. Here's some examples:

This shows `+65`, yet there was nothing new:

[image]

This shows `+5` yet IIRC the total should have been at least `+30`, ie. one new upvote per question, as the others had already been seen:

[image]

This shows `+151`, yet it should be `+15`:

[image]

As you can see, the difference in the values shown and the actual reputation I earned are not in sync at all, and almost seems random.

Comment: Thanks @yivi. Your google-foo is better than mine :)

Comment: It is just random virtual fake internet points. Or this is an A/B test to see how much we pay attention to that number.