# Reputation show again and again

Tags: bug, reputation

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640229/function-definition-with-initialized-arguments-and-function-call-with-less-argum) question today, and I got `7` upvotes means `70` reputation. I clicked on reputation tab and invisible my reputation. It is Ok.

But, After some time, it is also show `+70` upvotes on my reputation tab. Also, I clicked and invisible it. Then, After some time, I also, show `+70` upvotes.

So, I have a question, **Is it a software bug?**

Comment: Blame it on caching - it's a catch-all, like 'Too broad'.

Comment: Is your issue like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357579/reputation-notification-value-is-occasionally-wrong or do you see it somewhere else? if so, add a screenshot with free hand red circles.

Comment: Man, the dupe-search is terrible. I knew the exact title, so I typed in "rep bugging out", and it *still* didn't find that one.

Comment: @CodyGray Even when you copy paste a question title, it (often?) won't show up in the dupe search.